# Just created new calendar - does not receive invites from Outlook

Tags: google-calendar, outlook

I created a new Google calendar today. I want to send it invites from my corporate email account via Outlook. However it does not seem to be receiving/displaying the invites I'm sending it from Outlook. It's very strange because main Google Calendar (associated with my Gmail address) is able to receive invites from Outlook (and I have been sending it invites for years), but for some reason this new calendar does not. Here are the detailed steps I'm following to try to get the new calendar to receive/display Outlook invites:

1. In Calendar Settings > Calendar Details > Auto-accept invitations, I have selected "Automatically add all invitations to this calendar."
2. In Calendar Settings > Share This Calendar, I have not checked the box next to "Make this calendar public." I do not want this calendar showing up in Google search results.
3. In Calendar Settings > Share This Calendar, I added my corporate email address in the "Share with specific people" section. After about a minute I receive an email at my corporate email address asking me to accept the invitation and register my account. I click the link and the new Google calendar displays in my browser.
4. I create an event in Outlook, and in the "To:" section paste the address of my new Google calendar. The address has this format: [random numbers and letters]@group.calendar.google.com
5. The event does not show up in my Google calendar, even after I refresh it.

Curiously, in Step 4 I have tested sending the Outlook invite to both my main Google calendar (associated with my Gmail address) and the new Google calendar (that I created today). The event does display on my main Google calendar, so I know the invite can get through.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unanswered and not relevant.